# International eCommerce with Shopify

Tags: internationalization, shopify, currency

We are a USA based company with international presence and we are looking at setting up a store to sell digital goods worldwide through credit card purchases (i.e. no shipping involved). So far I've set up two accounts, one using a US postal address and one using a UK postal address,

1. The US postal address seems to give me an account that uses Shopify
   Payments for the payment gateway and only seems to be USD based.
2. The UK postal address gives me the option to use a payment gateway
   provided by someone called Sofort and all prices are in UK pounds.

At this rate of progress I'm going to need a mailing address and an email address and a unique site for every country in the world if we want to support local currencies. I guess I've missed the point somewhere soon the line, hence this request for guidance. Thanks!

What is the best strategy for us to use Shopify to sell to many countries worldwide in multiple currencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify doesn't offer multi-currency on the checkout process. You can display the prices in many currencies in your storefront (product.liquid, collections.liquid, cart.liquid....) but when user reaches checkout (https://checkout.shopify.com/carts/xxxx/ the displayed currency will be the Store default currency. You might want to give a try to [Shopify Plus](http://www.shopify.com/plus/?ref=microapps).

Opening multiple Shopify stores would solve this, but this is quite hard to maintain, unless you have the "master" store which serves as product database / CMS, and you send the checkouts to each particular store depending on the currency the buyer has choosen. So in this scenario, you'd have multiple Shopify stores serving only as "checkout processors".

Last but not least, Shopify is working on a Brand New Responsive Checkout and Theme Internationalization which will definitely be a step beyond on Internationalization. We can set you up a free [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) demo store which has this 2 new features enabled for you to evaluate whether it's worth waiting or not.

**UPDATE**
We've released this Shopify customization which allows you to accept as many currencies as you want in the Checkout: https://exclusive-checkout-demo.myshopify.com

Comment: Thanks for the offer but my deadline for go-live is Friday.

Answer (score -1):

I found a chat window to a Shopify guru who sent me these two links:

http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/currencies-and-translations/currencies/how-to-toggle-between-two-currencies

http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/currencies-and-translations/currencies/how-to-show-multiple-currencies

Comment: Remember that the charges will always happen in the Shop's currency. So even if you display CAD to me, if your shop's currency is USD that's what I'll be paying on the checkout.